# Android licenses status unknown? but when I try to run command flutter doctor --android-licenses it shows this?

Tags: flutter

Result when I run command `flutter doctor --android-licenses`:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

In most cases this command is helpful

```
flutter doctor –android-licenses
```

Also check the website
[licence_problem](https://flutteragency.com/fix-android-license-status-unknown/#:%7E:text=Fix%20Android%20License%20Status%20Unknown%20In%20Flutter%20Check,hitting%20y%20and%20it%20should%20solve%20the%20problem.)